# How to allow percona connection with root as non-sudo user on localhost?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, percona

I have default `root` user in my `percona` mysql8 installation.

Problem: when I first `sudo -s` and then `mysql -u root -prootpw`, then I can connect to the mysql. But I also want to allow nonroot users (eg a `java` application running under a nonroot account) to use the default user.

But I'm just getting:

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

So how can I force percona to allow `root` connections from localhost in non-root terminal users context?

Comment: mysql will always log you in when your user is root, regardless if you provide value via the -p argument. I suggest you create a separate user via `grant` command

Comment: What version of MySQL?  What do you mean by "default user"?  An app _should_ connect with a username specific to the app, _not_ root.

Comment: @RickJames I know that each app should have it's own user. But regardless of that, the question was: how to allow non-sudo users to connect as root/rootpw.

Comment: `sudo` should never be needed.  What ownership and permission does `/.../mysql` have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql > ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'rootpw';
mysql > FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
$ systemctl restart mysql
```

Comment: "Native password" applies only to newer versions.  I don't think the restart is needed.